# How to get actual mobile device screen size in web applications, javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I write mobile application based on Cordova and I have problem with screen sizes.

When I fetch screen sizes (for Nexus 4):

```
var sw = screen.width;
var  sh =  screen.height;
```

it gives me:

```
width: 768; height: 1184
```

However actual sizes (when I try to debug)

```
384 x 567
```

How to get actual screen size?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight
```